# How to split two textbox with an vertical bar with an OR text on it?

Tags: html, css

I have two text boxes:

```
<label class="q">A<input maxlength="9" /></label>
```

and

```
<label class="q">B<input maxlength="9" /></label>
```

I want to split these two boxes with a vertical line, on the center of the line, there's an "OR" text.

The idea was to make it clear to the user that input in either of the textbox is fine.

I tried using `float:left` and `float:right` to separate the two areas and use `border-left: 1px solid gray` as a separator, but how can I display a text in the middle of a vertical line?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MAEyF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to insert an element between them and inside it put the OR and the vertical line.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4hCUq/1/

---

Another would be to use CSS only for it (*by using pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` to insert the line and text*)

**HTML**

```
<label class="q">A<input maxlength="9" /></label>
<label class="q or">B<input maxlength="9" /></label>
```

**CSS**

```
.q{
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.or:before{
    content:' ';
    width:1px;
    height:150%;
    top:-25%;
    background-color:black;
    left:-25px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;

}
.or:after{
    content:'OR';
    left:-50px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:101;
    background-color:white;
    font-size:smaller;
    top:2px;
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
}
```

**CSS Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4hCUq/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Gaby aka G. Petrioli

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to tell what you're after without having an image of some sort, but you could try this:

```css
/* Target the pseudo-element :before on any label that follows another label */
label + label:before {
    content: "OR";
    color: red;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-size: 1px 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0, #000, #000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0, #000, #000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0, #000, #000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(0, #000, #000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(0, #000, #000);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5WrJu/

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot, but Gaby aka G. Petrioli's solution fits better for my situation. Sorry for being unclear.